# Closed form for Bessel type integral $\int_0^\infty J_0 (rx) \,\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, {\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Following [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709944/integrating-int-0-infty-fracu2-sqrtu2a2j-1rue-z-sqrtu2a2d/4714469#4714469), Zacky calculated the integral
$$\int_0^\infty x{J}_0(rx) \,\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\, {\rm d}x=\frac{e^{-a\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} \,.$$
It is a special case of the more general Bessel type integrals found in [Watson](https://archive.org/details/treatiseontheory00watsuoft/page/416/mode/2up).

I'm wondering if also a closed form expression for
$$\int_0^\infty {J}_0(rx) \,\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, {\rm d}x$$
can be found.

I tried the method Zacky applied, but it doesn't seem to work, because the appearance of error-functions complicate matters. I also tried the approach from Watson, but only converted the improper integral into a definite integral. Equation 2f (Watson, p.416) gives, while omitting the factor $t^{\mu+1}$, for $\nu=1/2$ and $\mu=0$
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}\int_0^\infty J_0(bt) \, \frac{e^{-a\sqrt{t^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{t^2+z^2}} \, {\rm d}t = \frac12 \int_0^\infty {\rm d}u \int_0^\infty {\rm d}t \, J_0(bt) \, u^{-3/2}\, e^{-\frac{a}{2}\left(u+\frac{t^2+z^2}{u}\right)} \\
=\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}} \int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}u}{u} \, I_0\left(\frac{b^2u}{4a}\right) \, e^{-\frac{(2a^2+b^2)u}{4a}-\frac{z^2a}{2u}}
$$
where the $t$-integral can be found [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E52). Substituting $v=\frac{b^2u}{4a}$ then gives
$$=\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}} \int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}v}{v} \, I_0(v) \, e^{-\frac{(2a^2+b^2)v}{b^2}-\frac{b^2z^2}{8v}} \, .$$
Using the representation $$I_0(v)=\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi {\rm d}\theta \, e^{-v\cos(\theta)}$$
finally yields
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi a}} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}\theta \int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}v}{v} \, e^{-\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)2v}{b^2}-\frac{b^2z^2}{8v}} \\
\stackrel{w=\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)2v}{b^2}}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi a}} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}\theta \int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}w}{w} \, e^{-w-\frac{\left(z\sqrt{a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta/2)}\right)^2}{4w}} \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}\theta \, K_0\left(z\sqrt{a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta/2)}\right)$$
resorting to this [integral representation of the Bessel-K-function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10).

Comment: This appears to be much much harder.. which I guess is also the reason why only the variant with odd powers is mentioned in that Watson book.

Comment: Yes, $$\frac1r\partial_r rJ_1(rx)=J_0(rx)x \, $$
so that case reduces to Zacky's.

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: If we put $U(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}),$ and insert $dU/dx=1/\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ in the integrand, and then integrate by parts, the first term is $-e^{-za} \ln(a)$ plus uglier integrals. I was hoping that a negative of the original integral would appear, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Next question could be: is your integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}} \int_0^\pi {\rm d}\theta \, \operatorname{K}_0\left(z\sqrt{a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta/2)}\right)$ equal to $\operatorname{I}_{0}\left(\tfrac{a}{2}\left[\sqrt{b^2+z^2}-z\right]\right) \operatorname{K}_0\left(\tfrac{a}{2}\left[\sqrt{b^2+z^2}+z\right]\right)?$

Comment: Numerically, yes :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Bateman's table of transforms, Vol. 2, page 31, #20, or Gradshteyn & Rhyzik, #6.637, we have
$$\int_0^\infty \operatorname{J}_0(rx) \,\frac{e^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, {\rm d}x
=\operatorname{I}_{0}\left(\tfrac{a}{2}\left[\sqrt{r^2+z^2}-z\right]\right) \operatorname{K}_0\left(\tfrac{a}{2}\left[\sqrt{r^2+z^2}+z\right]\right). 
$$
I have tested it numerically and it works. Integrals of this type appear in the paper by Dixon & Ferrar,
***Integrals for the product of two Bessel functions (II)***
by A. L. Dixon & W. L. Ferrar, The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, Volume os-4, Issue 1, 1933, Pages 297–304, at https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/os-4/1/297/1524326?redirectedFrom=fulltext.

Similar integrals, eqn. (4.7), also occur in the paper
***Analogue of a Fock-Type integral arising from electromagnetism and its applications in number theory*** by Atul Dixit and Arindam Roy, at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.03650.pdf.

The integral from Gradshteyn & Rhyzik, #6.645, is of the form
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}(x^2-1)^{-1/2}\,{\rm e}^{-\alpha x}J_{\nu}\left(\beta\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\,{\rm d}x=I_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}-\alpha\right)\right)
K_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}+\alpha\right)\right).
$$
If we put $x=\cosh t,\,\, \alpha=\xi-z,\,\,\beta=2(z\xi)^{1/2},\,\,\nu\mapsto 2\nu,$ the integral reduces to the form of Dixon & Ferrar,
$$ 
\operatorname{I}_{\mspace{1mu}\nu}(z)\operatorname{K}_{\nu}(\xi)=
\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{J}_{\mspace{1mu}2\nu}\left(
2(z\mspace{2mu}\xi)^{1/2}\operatorname{\sinh} t
\right)\,{\rm e}^{-(\xi-z\mspace{1mu})\operatorname{\cosh}t}\,{\rm d}t\, . 
$$

**Edit**

The required integral is
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{0}(rx)\,\frac{{\rm e}^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,{\rm d}x\, ,
$$
where, as far as the integration is concerned, $r,z,a$ are considered to be constants.

We can replace the exponential in the integrand by using Poisson's integral, which is discussed at the end of $\S25$ in the paper by J.W.L.$\!$ Glaisher, ***On Riccati’s Equation and its Transformations, and on some Definite Integrals which satisfy them***,  in Phil. Trans. R. Soc. London, Page 792, Vol.$\!$ 172, 1881 https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/epdf/10.1098/rstl.1881.0018 or on  page 186, $\S6.32,$ of Watson's Treatise, 2nd Edition, 1966. It can also be found on math.stackexchange: [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp(-ax^2-\frac b{x^2})\,dx$ for $a,b>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

The Poisson  integral representation is
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-\alpha^2 q^2-\frac{\beta^2}{q^2}}\,{\rm d}q=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\alpha}{\rm e}^{-2\alpha\beta}.
$$
This allows the integrand to be represented as
$$
\frac{{\rm e}^{-z\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-\frac{\left(x^2+a^2\right)q^2}{4}-\frac{z^2}{q^2}}\,{\rm d}q\, ,
$$
and the required integral becomes
$$
I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}q\,{\rm e}^{-\frac{a^2 q^2}{4}-\frac{z^2}{q^2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,J_{0}(rx)\,{\rm e}^{-\frac{x^2 q^2}{4}}.
$$
From  #$10.22.52$ of DLMF, Digital Library of Mathematical Functions, or Watson, $\S13.3, \#5,$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{0}(bt)\,{\rm e}^{-p^2t^2}\,{\rm d}t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2p}{\rm e}^{-\frac{b^2}{8p^2}}\,I_{0}\!\left(\frac{q^2 b^2}{8p^2}\right),
$$
where $I_{0}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. This gives
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}q}{q}\,{\rm e}^{-\frac{a^2q^2}{4}-\frac{2z^2+r^2}{2q^2}}\,I_{0}\!\left(\frac{r^2}{2q^2}\right)\, .
$$
Now put the integral representation ($\#32.10.1,$ DLMF) of the modified Bessel function of the first kind,
$$
I_{0}\!\left(\frac{r^2}{2q^2}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
{\rm e}^{\frac{r^2}{2q^2}\cos(\theta)}\,{\rm d}\theta\, ,
$$
normally defined over the interval $0$ to $\pi,$ but here represented over
the interval $0$ to $2\pi,$
into the integrand to give
$$
I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!\!{\rm d}\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{{\rm d}q}{q}\,{\rm e}^{-\frac{a^2q^2}{4}-\frac{2z^2+r^2-r^2\cos(\theta)}{2q^2}}.
$$
Substituting $v=aq/2$ then gives
$$
I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{{\rm d}v}{v}\,{\rm e}^{
 -v^2-\frac{\frac{a^2}{2}\left(  2z^2+r^2-r^2\cos(\theta)\right)    }{4v^2}
                                                 }.
$$
The $v$ integral represents the Macdonald modified Bessel function of the second kind, and from Watson, $\S6.22, \#15,$ its integral representation is
$$
K_{0}(\varpi)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{\tau-\frac{\varpi^2}{4\tau}}\,\frac{{\rm d}\tau}{\tau}\stackrel{\,\tau=p^2}{=}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{p^2-\frac{\varpi^2}{4p^2}}\,\frac{{\rm d}p}{p}\,.
$$
Putting $
\varpi=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2}\Bigl(2z^2+r^2-r^2\cos(\theta)\Bigr)},
$       the integral then assumes the form
$$
I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,
K_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2}\Bigl(2z^2+r^2-r^2\cos(\theta)\Bigr)}
     \,\,  \right)\,.
$$
If we introduce new constants defined by
$$
\lambda=\frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt{r^2+z^2}-z\right),\quad \mu=\frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt{r^2+z^2}+z\right),\tag{1}
$$
then we have
$$
\sqrt{\vphantom{Y^a}\lambda\mu}=ar/2,\quad \mu-\lambda=az,
$$
and this allows the quantity under the square root sign to be written as
$$
\varpi=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2}\Bigl(2z^2+r^2-r^2\cos(\theta)\Bigr)}=
\sqrt{\lambda^2+\mu^2-2\lambda\mu\cos(\theta)}\,.
$$
By Graf's addition formula, Watson $\S11.3,$ $\#8,$ and [A definite integral on a circle with Bessel functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829985/a-definite-integral-on-a-circle-with-bessel-functions/2830041#2830041), we can then write the integral as
$$
I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,
K_{0}\left(\varpi\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta\,
\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}I_{m}\left(\lambda\right)K_{m}\left(\mu\right)
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\mspace{1mu}m\mspace{1mu}\theta}\,.
$$
The integration over $\theta\mspace{1mu}$ leaves only the term with $m=0,$
and finally, by substituting for the Graf triangle constants, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ from $(1),$ we are left with the final form
$$
I=I_{0}\left(  \frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt{r^2+z^2} -z  \right)\right)
  K_{0}\left(  \frac{a}{2}\left(\sqrt{r^2+z^2} +z  \right)\right)\,.
$$
This derivation is similar to @Diger's, except that he replaced the exponential term in the required integral by a $K_{1/2}(z)=\frac{{\rm e}^{-z}}{z}\sqrt{\frac{\pi z}{2}}$ Bessel function integral representation. It may be possible to redefine the $a$'s and $b$'s in his last line into the $\lambda$'s and $\mu$'s.

Comment: I upvoted, but only accept derivation :-P

Comment: I didn't know of that Graf formula. I actually found a proof using the hypergeometric function, but I didn't quite like it, so I haven't posted it. I still may write it down here sometime. Thanks.

Comment: Different representations are always useful, so I would go ahead and post it. I assume the dislike of hypergeometric and Meijer G-function type representations is that you have to unwrap the arguments to see the contents in terms of easily recognisable special functions.