Bessel function half angle fourier series expansion
I came across this Fourier series formula in my workings.
$$
J_0(2 a \sin (\theta / 2)) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-i m \theta} J_m(a)^2
$$
$a$ is non-negative and $\theta$ is real. I checked it numerically with the code given below.
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jn

m, a, theta = 5, 3, 2.4

print(jn(0, 2*a*np.sin(theta/2)))

res = 0

for m in range(-1000, 1000):
    res += np.exp(-1j*m*theta) * jn(m, a)**2
    
print(res)

Is there an analogous result for other integer order Bessel functions?
$$
J_l(2 a \sin (\theta / 2)) = ?
$$
$l = 1, 2, 3,...$

This and other identities can be deduced from Graf's addition theorem, which can be expressed in terms of complex exponentials as
$$\mathscr{C}_\nu(w)e^{-i \nu \chi}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathscr{C}_{\nu+k}(u)J_k(v)e^{-i k \alpha}$$
Here $\mathscr{C}$ denotes a generic cylinder function and $u,v,\alpha,\chi$ are defined through the triangle below:

There is a condition on this sum, but I'll specialize to the case $\mathscr{C}=J$ and integer $\nu$ where this condition can be ignored. Furthermore, we take the isosceles case $u=v$. From this we deduce
$$\chi =\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2},\quad w=2u\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$$
Hence Graf's addition theorem becomes
$$J_\nu\left(2u\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)e^{-i \nu (\pi/2-\alpha/2)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_{\nu+k}(u)J_k(u)e^{-i k \alpha}$$
Taking $\nu=0$ then yields
$$J_0\left(2u\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_{k}(u)^2 e^{-i k \alpha}$$
which is the formula of interest. Taking other integer $\nu$ gives similar Fourier series; we could also use $\alpha=\pi-2\chi$ to obtain similar representations for $J_\nu(2u \cos \chi)$ instead.

For another formulation of the addition theorem, see the version here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830041/137524
